# upgrade an old "kinda" broken ubuntu from a working lubuntu

Tags: upgrade, lubuntu

i've been searching for this but i couldnt find an answer. (to state that i did search)

**is it possible to update my ubuntu 11.04 from my current Lubuntu 13.10 ?**

i have and "old" pc. specs are:
cpu: amd athlon xp @1.9
vga: ati radeon 9200 agp 8x
ram: 1 gb module - 1 module for 256 mb total: 1,25gb
motherboard: a7v8x-mx se

a few years ago i installed ubuntu 10.04, put a lot of important files there, and kinda "never used it again", i just used ubuntu once or twice in a year, when searching for old stuff.
my ubuntu was working fine, but i couldnt upload videos to youtube anymore. firefox just freeze and chrome crashes.
so i uninstaled chrome and i couldnt install it back, because my version was not supported anymore. so i started upgrading (it was quite difficult because im a begginer)
and i managed to upgrade to 11.04.

when trying to upgrade to 11.10, linux wont let me log in, the clock on the login screen works, but i cant move the mouse, cant use the keyboard and cant enter a terminal (with alt + f2) i read that it wont load up my video card drivers or maybe its the mouse and keyboard.

entering text mode allows me to perform console commands such as "sudo upgrade" , but since the LIST file is "broken" and i have to replace some lines to the "old-repository" it wont upgrade anymore, it will never find the files required.

i tried to install 12.04 but the install fails (like its some hardware problem).
tired of reading, i find that the problem is my old video card, so i moved into a "light" version of linux and here i am, it works just fine, even faster i think.

im in Lubuntu 13.10 and i love it, but i CANT use the flash player, only a few sites allow me to use the flash, i try with chrome and cant even run the chrome browser.

so im ok with that, but, **is it possible to update my ubuntu 11.04 from my current Lubuntu 13.10 ?**

11.04 ubuntu has 65 gb in a 80 gb ide hdd
so im afraid that i might run out of space soon in this 15gb filesystem.

the files i had are OK, i can access all of them from here, i just cant use flash.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds more like you should be looking for a way to get flash working. 11.04 had MANY issues, actually rendered my computer inoperable until 12.04 came out (I was forced to use Winbloze until then). When I installed 13.10 I had the same issue with flash. The issue is that Ubuntu no longer ships with flash.

In the software center try looking for the package Adobe Flash Plugin. This should give you the latest version of flash available for Ubuntu. Your browser will need to be restarted after the fact though. You may also install the app in the terminal window with:

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

Comment: is it possible then, uninstall the 11.04, then re assign disk space  and also "claim" the files, merging the 65gb partition into a whole partition for the Lubuntu filesystem, before its full in its 15 gb hdd space?

how is it done?

Comment: My recommendation here would by to use a Live CD. This allows you to access the files on your drive but run the OS from your RAM. Then you can copy the files to a safe location and with gparted (still in the Live mode, you may have to download through software center) you may delete the partitions and create a new partition with the sum of the unallocated space. If there is a partition between the two on the physical location you may have to play musical partitions moving the data around to get everything sorted how you want. And external HD would help greatly if this is the case.

Comment: i switched to linux after a hard disk failure, i dont have spare hdd's. i can access the files in the 65 gb partition just mounting it from the Lubuntu, and yes, i can back them up (maybe in another borrowed pc or a cloud storage), but i just dont want to, i want to update the linux there from "outside"

Comment: its just that i dont want to format the linux partition, and yes, Lubuntu is very nice, runs pretty well, but i cant use flash, i've been reading and it seems that my old amd processor and the latest chrome arent compatible (wich sucks cause chrome is now the only flash option), so i might run into the same after the ubuntu upgrade, but at least, i will have the disk the way i want it, not having to mount or unmount the unit everytime i need to listen to mp3 or look at pictures.

isnt anyway that i can "recover" an ubuntu install without format?

Comment: If there are only 2 partitions on the drive you may move all desired files to one partition, then using gparted in Live mode you can delete the unwanted partition (ie. the 11.04 partition) and then extend the 65GB partition. No format or OS reinstall required.

Comment: Also curious, did the plugin installer help the flash issue in 13.10 for you?

Comment: that's a very good answer. i will try later in live mode merging the partitions.
about the flash, since it doesnt work in my cpu, i found the way around it doing this:
installed opera browser, downloader flash player 11.1 and paste it into the plugin section of opera.
yes, im aware that doing that, im exposed to security issues, but i just cant browse the net without youtube and other sites that requieres flash.

well, i just need to merge the partitions then, and that will be it.

thanks for your help!